# How do we call a concept when my acceptor loop is ran by some real application while all services are plugins for that application?

Tags: concepts, plugins, server, services

So say we have an app (server) that somehow attaches to itself plugins (services) in form of .dll or .so libraries. Is there any nice short name for such server behaviour model?

Comment: A plugin architecture?

Comment: A plugin architecture would relate to all kinds of programms. Isnt there any special server/service related name?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding your description, but if you have a server that loads libraries to get additional services, that is a plugin-based architecture. You could also call it service-oriented architecture, which has several guidelines as to what makes it [service oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-orientation).

Comment: Iey!) service oriented is what I looked for. Please,  post is as an answer please=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture can be probably be genericized as a plugin-based architecture, where the server gets functionality from loading libraries.

Your model also fits the idea of [service-oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), where a software system contains different services that operate together.